# Qt .pro file dependencies for compiling a .cpp file

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I am running and compiling my c++ code using linux terminal gcc commands. I want to compile and run the code from qt. I am struggling to understand the dependencies I have to convert from console command to qt dependencies in .pro file. Console command for compiling the project is the following:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -c -g -MMD -MP -MF main.o.d -o main.o main.cpp
gcc -c -g `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -MMD -MP -MF svmlight/svm_learn.o.d -o svmlight/svm_learn.o svmlight/svm_learn.c
gcc -c -g `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -MMD -MP -MF svmlight/svm_hideo.o.d -o svmlight/svm_hideo.o svmlight/svm_hideo.c
gcc -c -g `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -MMD -MP -MF svmlight/svm_common.o.d -o svmlight/svm_common.o svmlight/svm_common.c
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o trainhog main.o svmlight/svm_learn.o svmlight/svm_hideo.o svmlight/svm_common.o `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

The created .pro file in qt is the following:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

How can I add those dependencies from console command to qt .pro file? I tried to compile my project with the following *.pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
INCLUDEPATH += path/svmlight/

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core
//I add all necessary opencv libs
```

However I am getting several undefined references for 'my_malloc' 'verbosity' 'free model'...
 main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `my_malloc'

```
  main.o:-1: In function `SVMlight::~SVMlight()':
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD2Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x15):-1: error: undefined reference to `kernel_cache_cleanup'
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD2Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x29):-1: error: undefined reference to `free_model'
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD2Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x4e):-1: error: undefined reference to `free_example'   
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD0Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x15):-1: error: undefined reference to `kernel_cache_cleanup'
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD0Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x29):-1: error: undefined reference to `free_model'
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD0Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x4e):-1: error: undefined reference to `free_example'
 (.text._ZN8SVMlightD0Ev[_ZN8SVMlightD5Ev]+0x4e):-1: error: undefined reference to `free_example'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of available commands for `*.pro` files [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html).

For your purpose you should look at [`INCLUDEPATH`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath), [`LIBS`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) and probably some of the `FLAG` keywords.

The errors you are getting seem to belong to the `svmlight` Lib. From what you show from your pro-file you have only included `LIBS` that belong to `opencv`, not those of `svmlight`

Comment: I add include files and libs of opencv. How is it possible to add the .h files of svmlight? Which is actually a dir of files in my computer? I just have to add another inclupath for svmlight?

Comment: The includepath is only needed for `<include>` commands in your code so yes, adding the includepath for that should be enough

Comment: I add INCLUDEPATH += /path/svmlight/ however I am getting errors as  I mentioned in edited post.

Comment: svmLight is just header fiels c files and ojects. It doesnt include any lib file.

Comment: Please check the [svmlight FAQ](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) on how to integrate it into c++ code. You then have to link those `*.o`files mentioned there

Comment: Svmlight doesn't contain a .lib it just creates two executable files which I want to call from main.

Comment: The console code it works normally producing executable files.